# What is the poem uttered by the saint in Dasavatharam?

Tags: dialogue, dasavathaaram

In the Tamil movie *Dasavatharam* (*The Ten Avatars*), while 12th century scene starts, there is a saint who utters some Tamil poem. I heard it many times, but even can't figure out the starting word. What poem is that? You can find the scene [here](https://youtu.be/kKoSpuCRC9g?t=45).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First one is from **Tamil**. He speaks in the literary form asking all to pray Lord Shiva.

*Lyrics:*

```
உயர்வாழ நெடுதூழி உய்வாக முதலீறு புகல் வேத நூல்,
இயல் வாழ உமை வாழ்வது ஒரு பாகர் இருதாளில் இசை பாடுவோம்
```

*Transliteration*

```
Uyarvaazha neduthoozi uyvaaga mudhaleeru pugal veda nool,
iyal vaazha umai vaazva thorupaagar iru thaaLil isai paaduvom
```

*Meaning*

```
Let's pray lord shiva, who has given equal status to Uma (Parvati) [Arthanarishvara]
```

The second is a vedic hymn in **Sanskrit**, glorifying Lord Shiva.

**Lyrics:**

```
नमस्तेस्तु भगवन् |
विश्वेश्वराय महादेवाय |
त्रैय्मबकाय त्रिपुरान्तकाय |
त्रिकाग्नि कालाय |
कालाग्नि रुद्राय नीलकण्ठाय मृत्युंजयाय |
सर्वेश्वराय सदाशिवाय श्रीमान महादेवाय नमः ||
```

**Transliteration:**

```
Namasthe asthu bhagavan
visweswaraaya mahaadevaaya
tryambakaaya Tripuraanthakaaya trikagni
kaalaaya kaalaagni rudhraaya neela kantaaya Mrutyumjayaaya 
sarveshwaraya sadashivaaya sriman maha devaaya nama
```

*Meaning:*

```
Let's pray the lord
king of the world, lord of lords
one who has destroyed tripurams (three forts made in iron, silver, gold)
one with three eyes (sun, moon, agni-fire power)
rudra [anger and kills evil], one with blue neck (ate devastating poison and saved people. his wife parvati pressed at neck to prevent the poison from entering his body)
lord of lords, lord of all time, the great lord
```

Comment: Good work. May I know where you got the resource?

Comment: Can i know the author and book of those poems? @SibiCoder